# cannot access proftpd installation from outside server

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, ufw, proftpd

I have a digitalocean droplet running ubuntu 18 with Apache. I installed proftpd on there and when I log in to the droplet via ssh and run `ftp myservertld`  or `telnet myservertld 21` I can access the proftpd instance properly. However when I try to connect to it from my pc via filezilla, terminal or browser, or even from another separate droplet, I cannot connect to the ftp server, the connection simply times out. On filezilla I am getting this:

```
Status: Resolving address of myservertld
Status: Connecting to IP:21...
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

Answer (score 1):

I simply forgot to open the port in firewall

```
ufw allow 21/tcp
```